# concatenate values over rows and sum up corresponding values

Tags: python, pandas

I use panda to read a timesheet excel and want to group particular rows for the same day and same customer. So my dataframe is something like that:

| Customer | Day | Comment | Effort |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 02.02.2024 | Topic A | 2 |
| A | 02.02.2024 | Topic B | 2 |
| B | 02.02.2024 | Cleaning | 4 |
| A | 03.02.2024 | Topic A | 2 |
| B | 03.02.2024 | Cleaning | 2 |
| B | 03.02.2024 | Telco | 4 |

I tried groupby and and I got the sum of effort but i didn't get the commment join working

What I want to achive is an overview per customer per day, concatenate the comment and sum up the effort for same customer and same day:

| Customer | Day | Comment | Effort |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 02.02.2024 | Topic A, Topic B | 4 |
| A | 03.02.2024 | Topic A | 2 |
| B | 02.02.2024 | Cleaning | 4 |
| B | 03.02.2024 | Cleaning, Telco | 6 |

Comment: `df.groupby(['Customer', 'Day'], as_index=False).agg({'Comment': ', '.join, 'Effort': 'sum'})`